# Which concept in physics is closest to the general concept of power?

Tags: single-word-requests

The general concept of power, as in [social and political power](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_(social_and_political)), but also as in "power levels", is very different from the concept of [power in physics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_%28physics%29) (where it refers to the rate of doing work). Since power is a bad fit, which concept in physics is closest to the general concept of power?

Comment: Hardly about the English or any language. It's perhaps a matter for the guys at [philosophy.se] or sociology.

Comment: Gregory Bateson argues that "power" is a physical metaphor which has no applicability in the biological world. Power applies to locomotives and nuclear generators but not to mental process or human interactions. To apply the metaphor of "power" to biological systems is dangerous to the ecology of living process.

Comment: "All metaphors derived from a physical world of impacts, forces, energy, etc., are unacceptable in explanations of events and processes in the biological world of information, purpose, context, organization and meaning".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it would be *energy*, which represents the amount of work something can do (with no reference to rate).

Comment: +1 and I think we can be even more specific and say it's [potential energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_energy).

Answer (score 2):

Power, outside physics, is not really power. It's a [Metaphor](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Metaphors.pdf); that's not a different meaning, exactly.
Rather, it's an extension from an original context to a context outside the original.

Political or social *power* is, essentially, the ability, talent, or habit (or whichever noun you please)
of getting other people to do things one wants them to. People who can and do that successfully
are said to have (some degree of) **power** over the people who do the stuff one wants them to.

Since this is "spooky action at a distance", as Einstein put it, the closest thing in physics
that I can think of is nonlocal boson entanglement. This is difficult to attain and observe in physics, but in society and politics, people are multiply entangled and, while there is real local contact between people, most relations between people are virtual, in the sense that they occur to humans in imagination and projection rather than in actual conversation. 
This includes all of one's relations with "The Boss/Law/Government/Police/Authorities", as they may be known.

Most power results from people doing things automatically, so taking and keeping political or social power is mostly a matter of (to use a different metaphor) finding the biggest parade and making sure you're leading it.

Answer (score 0):

I would say "Potential" or "Force". Both will work in different situations though.

`Potential`: when you say a person has power to do some task (capability)

`Force`: when someone applies power (in physics, one is applying force)

Comment: I wanted to say `Energy` too, but it would represent `stamina` in general usage

Comment: Force is not the application of power

Comment: @DaveS Off course not, see answer again (**Hint**: see the following brackets)

Comment: In general usage, we say "A punched B with all his power" or "X used his power to drag the table". Both these uses comply with *force* in physics.

Did you say **application of force**? I said the same, whether or not it is applied over a distance (`d = 0`).

Comment: For example, in general use, `A used all his power but couldn't move the truck`, He applied power/force but no distance, see. Zero work in physics

Comment: I don't think the statements you have made are general. You said "Force: when someone applies power (in physics, one is applying force)".

Comment: When two wrestlers try to push each other, in general English usage, the more powerful one will push other, In physics, the one with more force. Can't argue more.

I mentioned it clearly though that it is not the only candidate, potential is the other one, which fits most other situations.

Comment: And `power` in **Force: when someone applies power (in physics, one is applying force)** is general use of the word, not a physics term (*if that is the confusion*)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't agree that you should be use airy-fairy definitions for power. Power has a precise definition, energy per unit time, use it.

Comment: Seriously? The question is "which concept in physics is closest to the **general concept of power**?" So I am using general concept to establish equivalent in Physics.

Comment: Sorry, I went off on a tangent, forgetting the original question. However, in your answer to the question, you state that "in physics, one is applying force". I didn't, and still don't, feel comfortable with this statement. That is all.

Answer (score 0):

Power can be measured by depth and breadth; so, a media baron has a small amount of power over a large number of people, but a mayor of a small town has a large amount of power over relatively few people. The former is broad, the latter is deep.

Compare that with the equation for certain types of force: `F = A rʰ`. A represents the "depth" of the power, whereas the exponent of r (-2 for gravity or electromagnetism) represents the breadth.

And conveniently enough, forces of the form `F = A rʰ` are called [power-law forces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_law).

Comment: *Force* already has a sociological usage. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_%28law%29